# Throwing custom exception from generic method - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA, and i have a **generic method** that returns a generic type object and a **custom exception** that needs to be thrown from the generic method.
Unfortunately, I get an error from the IDE suggesting that I should throw the generic **Throwable** instead of my custom exception. Whenever I try to throw my exception, I get a compilation error.

The generic method -> Gets one of three client types from the database, or throws an **ClientNotFoundException** stating that the client wasn't found in db:

```
    public static <T> T isExists(JpaRepository repository, int id, ClientType clientType) throws Throwable {
    T fromDB = (T) repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ClientNotFoundException("Error getting info from dababase", Calendar.getInstance(), null, clientType));
    return fromDB;
}
```

What seems to be the problem? How can I throw my custom exception from my generic method? Thanks :)

*edited*:
If I manually throw from method header **ClientNotFoundException**, the lines go red and the app is not compiling-

The compilation error that I get is:

```
java: unreported exception java.lang.Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

IDE (using IntelliJ) suggests 3 options:

- Convert exception to Throwable
- Annotate with @SneakyThrows
- try/catch

The suggestions are not the best for me, so I'd like to check other solutions..

Comment: Replacing `throws Throwable` with `throws ClientNotFoundException` does not work? If not: please [edit] the post and include the compilation error. --- As an aside: `isExists(...)` is a terrible name. Renaming the method to `doesExist(...)` does not make it better; I would then expect the method to return a `boolean` instead of a `T`.

Comment: Edited! and sure, the name is a horrible option, it's just temporary

Comment: Obvious question - your exception class is subclassed (directly or indirectly) from Exception, right?

Comment: Sure, it extends Exception

Comment: "unreported Exception"?? "must be caught or declared to be thrown" - are you handling the Exception (`catch` or `throws`) where the method is being called?

Comment: Oh no, I just need to throw it to the Controller

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  This was fixed quite a while back, I believe: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8054569.  I can't reproduce your issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ended with workaround:

```
E entity = (E) repository.findById(entityId).orElse(null);
if (entity == null){
    throw new NonexistentEntityException(String.format("%s with id=%d not exists", keyName, entityId));
}
```